# OpenGL how to bind (tens of) thousands of textures at once?

Tags: opengl, 3d

So I was playing around with opengl and ran into a bit of a problem. I want to be able to use a very large amount (upwards of 15k) of small (128x128) 2D textures at once (during a single draw call). Problem is I can't figure out how to do it efficiently. Here are the approaches and their problems I have found so far:

1. As far as I understand the standard solution to multiple textures is a GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY but that usually doesn't have a max size anywhere near big enough
2. As an alternative I could use GL_TEXTURE_3D which, usually, has a much greater allowed depth, but, as I understand, I would have to generate mipmaps manually (or maybe even not use them at all?) and could have color bleed between the layers due to floating point errors if there are thousands of layers
3. I could try using a GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY of texture atlases, but then I would also have to think of how to solve mipmapping or wrapping problems as well as color bleed
   Can someone please recommend a better way if there is one, or say which is better of the ones I have outlined and if I am overlooking anything?

Comment: You could also generate a texture atlas and split your draw call into several with different textures.

Comment: What's the point? That much texture data takes over 1GB of VRAM, and you don't even have nearly as many pixels on the screen. Sounds like the right thing to do is to figure out which of those textures contribute to the final image, and maintain a single GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY just for those textures.

Comment: @YakovGalka the point is that I'm trying to write a(nother minecraft-like) voxel engine, and one of the things I want to try implement is a ridiculous render distance and very large variety of voxel types, so the many thousands of textures can be on the screen all at once. I could, say, calculate the textures used per-chunk, but then I would have to re-upload at least some of them to the gpu multiple times per frame which seemed suboptimal. Besides, while it will be 1 GB of VRAM, maybe even 2 or 3, but that will be basically it, which doesn't seem unreasonable for having everything in-memory

Comment: I would go with 3. Since the textures are power of 2 (128) there won't be any problem with mipmapping (just make sure textures don't go smaller than 1 pixel). You could have problems with bilinear, but I think that for this kind of game you want to have it disabled anyways! Otherwise, I would go with multiple draw calls with texture arrays. Bindless textures are also something to consider if your user base supports it.

Comment: @DFined That is a very fine experiment, but you will find out there is a reason voxel engines don't actually work this way. All good game engines spend a ton of effort trying to reduce the amount of stuff that is drawn, without the player being able to notice that less stuff is being drawn.

Comment: Well yeah, I know. And I am planning to have LODs and colored vertices for far away stuff. But it must definitely be possible, because minecraft, the origin of this horrible mistake of a coding experiment, can easily have many thousands of active textures once you load a few big mods and, I may be wrong, but from what I was able to find out about it, I do believe it keeps them loaded in-VRAM. I know minecraft used to use texture atlases but not sure if it does anymore... I guess I should probably try atlases in any case, see how it goes

Comment: From what I can tell, vanilla minecraft uses 16x16 textures and pretty short rendering distances. With most GPUs supporting at least 8192x8192 textures, you can have 262144 unique textures within the atlas. (Disclaimer: I didn't ever play minecraft.) Also note that if you want to render some extremely far geometry, you'll run into other problems (z-buffer resolution, vertex count, aliasing due to geometry finer than pixels). To solve those you'd need to completely change the way you render far geometry, e.g. by projecting it onto a cube texture.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't actually know about z-buffer resolution being a problem, will have to account for that somehow. But yeah, I think vanilla minecraft doesn't even have enough textures for them to be a problem in an array on modern hardware, let alone in an atlas. But I will probably have to try use an array of atlases I guess, but I should only need a few

Answer (score 2):

A bit of a follow up in case anyone has the same problem.

I chose to try the 3-rd option I outlined in the question (using TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY with each layer being a texture atlas generated from separate textures at startup) and can indeed confirm that, while not ideal and somewhat unconventional, it does, at least, work. Moreover, while it is unusual to use a texture atlas array as if it was a single atlas, texture atlases themselves are very well practiced and easy to research.

I tested it with only a few textures in total so far, but, in theory, with a typical 8192x8192x2048 2D texture array of atlases I could have up to 8 million 128x128 textures (though in practice the actual number would, of course, be far less due to VRAM limitations)

[image: The proof of concept - a simple 1024x1024 block world with some different textures loaded through an atlas array]